# Click on the Checkbox inside the Label or Div

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to create the two methods, one for clicking on the specific checkbox and second for de-selecting the same checkbox.
I was trying to using the XPath and ID but unable to do so.
Please tell me how it can be done. Here is the HTML:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;
            js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(200,document.body.scrollHeight)", "");
            var mileageTextbox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("VehicleMileageMax"));
            mileageTextbox.SendKeys("9500");
            var checkBox = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[text()='financial-check-all-8']::input[@type='checkbox'")); 
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            checkBox.Click();
```

Element is not visible

HTML code :

```
<input id="financial-check-all-8" type="checkbox" selected="filter.isDisabled" ng-model="filter.isDisabled" ng-change="vm.emptyFilterValue(filter);" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" aria-invalid="false" tabindex="44"> <label for="financial-check-all-8" id="enabled-8" class="form-checkbox-label"></label>
```

Comment: If element is not visible is the exception you are getting, then May be element is obscure by other element. How do you interact with this element manually anyway ?

Comment: I have tried with all the locators, but unable to locate the element.

Comment: Can you share the HTML code for that radio button.

Comment: <input id="financial-check-all-8" type="checkbox" selected="filter.isDisabled" ng-model="filter.isDisabled" ng-change="vm.emptyFilterValue(filter);" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" aria-invalid="false" tabindex="44">                                <label for="financial-check-all-8" id="enabled-8" class="form-checkbox-label"></label>

Comment: Please confirm, if it is working?

Comment: Can you check in developer tools that how many entries are present for `//input[starts-with(@id,'financial-check-all') and @ng-model='filter.isDisabled']`

Comment: @ajaykumar To select and deselect the checkbox you need to update the question with the HTML of both the stages.

Comment: HTML is updated

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code :

```
//input[starts-with(@id,'financial-check-all') and @ng-model='filter.isDisabled']
```

**Code :**

```
var checkBox = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[starts-with(@id,'financial-check-all') and @ng-model='filter.isDisabled']")); 
checkBox.Click();
```

**EDIT :**
As per the Shared HTML you can use this xpath: 
try to wait also before clicking on it, Just try with `Thread.Sleep(4000);` , If that works then we can easily replace that with **webdriverwait**.

```
//label[@for='VehicleMileageMax']/../preceding-sibling::div/descendant::input
```

or with this xpath :

```
//label[@for='VehicleMileageMax']/../preceding-sibling::div/descendant::label
```